# PGError: ERROR: column "inboxes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following query to MySQL database:

```
SELECT inboxes.*
   , count(inboxes.conv) AS times
   , max(created_at) AS created_at
FROM `inboxes`
WHERE to_user = 2
   OR account_id = 2
GROUP BY conv
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This query works on my localhost, but if I deploy it to Heroku, I'll get this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "inboxes.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or
                 be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify all fields in `GROUP BY`, which you wanna select, ie:

`SELECT inboxes.id, count(inboxes.conv) AS times, max(created_at) as created_at FROM`inboxes`WHERE (to_user = 2 OR account_id = 2) GROUP BY inboxes.id, conv ORDER BY inboxes.id DESC`

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. But what if I need to work with all columns in table? And the next stuf - when I use `GROUP BY inboxes.id, conv`, so I get an other output than if I use only `GROUP BY conv`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid problems like this in the future, install postgres locally and develop your application with the same database it is using in production.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the `inboxes.*`. List each single parameter you need to fetch.

All parameters must be either grouped (`GROUP BY`) or used together with a group function(`MAX`, etc.).

I cannot tell you why its working on your localhost.